# ClientKeyExchange in static DH

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, key-exchange, openssl

I am confused about the content of ClientKeyExchange in case if the key-exchange is static DH. The TLS 1.2 standard says under section 7.4.7 in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-57:

> If the client is sending a certificate containing a static
> DH exponent (i.e., it is doing fixed_dh client authentication),
> then this message MUST be sent but MUST be empty.

Is it always the case that static DH means that the client will send the static DH in a client Certificate? What is the client does not have a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it always the case that static DH means that the client will send the static DH in a client Certificate? What is the client does not have a certificate?

If the client does not have a certificate, then the requirement you quoted doesn't apply, as the condition "If the client is sending a certificate ..." is not met.

Instead, the DH public key is sent in the ClientKeyExchange handshake (exactly as if your DH wasn't static).